# How to use XPATH to return an array of values based on a condition that a specific property exists in a JSON object array

Tags: xpath, power-automate

How can I use XPATH to return an array based on the existence of a specific property?
Below is a section of my JSON file. Under "root" there are a number of array objects and SOME of them contain the property "detection". I would like to retrieve the "service_name" of each array object ONLY IF the object array (under root) contains the property "detection".

e.g., "service_name": "IPS" should be returned

[image]

but for the example below, the service_name should NOT be returned because property "detection" is not present

[image]

Finally, is there a way to combine the above query into one, in order to return an array of values "service_name" and "detection" together, based on the same condition?

My current Power Automate Set Variable command is:

```
xpath(xml(variables('varProductsRoot')), '//detection | //service_name')
```

and unfortunately it returns ALL service_names, even if the component they belong to does not contain the "detection" property.

Below is a sample of my JSON file I am trying to parse

```
{
  "root": {
    "fg": [
      {
        "product_name": "fg",
        "remediation": {
          "type": "package",
          "packages": [
            {
              "service": "ips",
              "service_name": "IPS",
              "description": "Detects and Blocks attack attempts",
              "kill_chain": {
                "step": "Exploitation"
              },
              "link": "https://fgd.fnet.com/updates",
              "minimum_version": "22.414"
            }
          ]
        },
        "detection": {
          "attackid": [
            51006,
            50825
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "fweb": [
      {
        "product_name": "fWeb",
        "remediation": {
          "type": "package",
          "packages": [
            {
              "service": "waf",
              "service_name": "Web App Security",
              "description": "Detects and Blocks attack attempts",
              "kill_chain": {
                "step": "Exploitation"
              },
              "link": "https://fgd.fnet.com/updates",
              "minimum_version": "0.00330"
            }
          ]
        },
        "detection": {
          "signature_id": [
            "090490119",
            "090490117"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "fcl": [
      {
        "product_name": "fcl",
        "remediation": {
          "type": "package",
          "packages": [
            {
              "service": "vuln",
              "service_name": "Vulnerability",
              "description": "Detects and Blocks attack attempts",
              "kill_chain": {
                "step": "Delivery"
              },
              "link": "https://fgd.fnet.com/updates",
              "minimum_version": "1.348"
            }
          ]
        },
        "detection": {
          "vulnid": [
            69887,
            2711
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "product_name": "fcl",
        "remediation": {
          "type": "package",
          "packages": [
            {
              "service": "ob-detect",
              "service_name": "ob Detection",
              "kill_chain": {
                "step": "sm/SOAR"
              },
              "link": "https://www.fgd.com/services",
              "minimum_version": "1.003"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "fss": [
      {
        "product_name": "fss",
        "remediation": {
          "type": "package",
          "packages": [
            {
              "service": "ips",
              "service_name": "IPS",
              "description": "Detects and Blocks attack attempts",
              "kill_chain": {
                "step": "Exploitation"
              },
              "link": "https://fgd.fnet.com/updates",
              "minimum_version": "22.414"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "fadc": [
      {
        "product_name": "fADC",
        "remediation": {
          "type": "package",
          "packages": [
            {
              "service": "ips",
              "service_name": "IPS",
              "description": "Detects and Blocks attack attempts",
              "kill_chain": {
                "step": "Exploitation"
              },
              "link": "https://fgd.fnet.com/updates",
              "minimum_version": "22.414"
            }
          ]
        },
        "detection": {
          "ips_rulename": [
            "Error.Log.Remote.Code.Execution",
            "Server.cgi-bin.Path.Traversal"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "product_name": "fADC",
        "remediation": {
          "type": "package",
          "packages": [
            {
              "service": "waf",
              "service_name": "Web App Security",
              "description": "Detects and Blocks attack attempts",
              "kill_chain": {
                "step": "Exploitation"
              },
              "link": "https://fgd.fnet.com/updates",
              "minimum_version": "1.00038"
            }
          ]
        },
        "detection": {
          "sigid": [
            1002017267,
            1002017273
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "fsm": [
      {
        "product_name": "fsm",
        "remediation": {
          "type": "package",
          "packages": [
            {
              "service": "ioc",
              "service_name": "IOC",
              "kill_chain": {
                "step": "sm/SOAR"
              },
              "link": "https://www.fgd.com/services",
              "minimum_version": "0.02355"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance,
Nikos

Comment: Can you please post your json AS TEXT so we can produce a proper answer for you?

Comment: Hi @Skin, I just updated my post with a sample JSON. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you.  I've broken it up into three steps for ease ...

[image: Flow]

#### Step 1

This contains your JSON as you provided.  The variable is defined as an `Object`.

#### Step 2

Initialise a string variable that contains the following expression ...

```
xml(variables('JSON'))
```

... which (as you know) will convert the JSON to XML.

#### Step 3

This is an `Array` variable that will extract the values of all `service_name` elements where the `detection` element exists, using the following expression ...

```
xpath(xml(variables('XML')), '//detection/..//service_name/text()')
```

#### Result

Voila!  You have your values in an array.

[image: Result]

Comment: Excellent answer! Very well described. Thank you very much :)